# Language validation with xstate

Tags: xstate

I have the following state diagram that is for validating whether a string matches a format.
[image: state diagram]

I would like to recreate this language matching fsm in xstate. The machine should return *true* for `ac`, `abc`, `abbbbbc` etc and otherwise *false*. It should have exactly the same output as the regex expression `string.match(/^ab*c$/) !== null;`

I currently have the following:

```js
const machine = Machine({
    initial: 'start',
    states: {
        start: {
            on: {A: 'state1'}
        },
        state1: {
            on: {
                B: 'state1',
                C: 'end'
            }
        },
        end: {}
    }
});
```

Is there a way through actions and context I can check if a string matches this language fsm through it reaching the *end* state.

Of course I could just use regex but I have simplified the problem for the purpose of this so question. The actual language I want to parse is not regular and requires pda / context. I just want to know the structure of using xstate for language / string parsing.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a go :) Join me here if you wish: https://codesandbox.io/s/xstate-simple-regex-style-parser-pww28

Comment: @Glutnix Looks very interesting, a lot more complex than I thought though. I guess xstate isn't really built for language parsing. Instead I have landed on a method of switching through a ts enum.

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkRegex =(content,event)=>{
if(event.match(/^ab*c$/) !== null){
context.valid =true;
}
}
const regexMachine = Machine({
initial: 'state1',
states: {
    state1:{
        on:{
          VALIDATE: {
                target:"state2"
               }
        }
     }
    state2: {
        invoke:{
              src:(context,event)=>checkRegex(event)},
              onDone:{target:"end"}
              onError:{target:"state1"}
    },
    end: {
         type: "final"
     }
}
});
```

Component Usage:

```
const [current,send] = useMachine(regexMachine);

send("VALIDATE","aaabbbcc");
```